# Multiple Json payload in POST call using Jmeter

Tags: json, file, csv, post, jmeter

There is a json payload for registering a user. I have given the filename in the CSV file and gave the `filetostring()` function in body. But still the api is not posting it. Given below the log and using Jmeter5.1. Any suggestions?

`${__FileToString(C:/${__eval({regusr})}.txt,,)}`

`${__FileToString(C:/${({regusr})}.txt,,)}`

```
2019-11-01 22:28:16,112 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting
ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 2019-11-01 22:28:16,112 INFO
o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread
Group. 2019-11-01 22:28:16,112 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine:
Thread will continue on error 2019-11-01 22:28:16,112 INFO
o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1
ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false 2019-11-01 22:28:16,113 INFO
o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 2019-11-01
22:28:16,113 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have
been started 2019-11-01 22:28:16,114 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread
started: Thread Group 1-1 2019-11-01 22:28:16,114 INFO
o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: C:\auth_reg.csv 2019-11-01 22:28:16,301
INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1 2019-11-01
22:28:16,302 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group
1-1 2019-11-01 22:28:16,302 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine:
Notifying test listeners of end of test 2019-11-01 22:28:16,302 INFO
o.a.j.s.FileServer: Close: C:\auth_reg.csv 2019-11-01 22:28:16,303
INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just read the dynamic files body you can omit the [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) and just use

```
${__FileToString(${regusr}.txt,,)}
```

if your JSON payload files contain [JMeter Functions and/or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which you want to get evaluated/substituted in the runtime you should be wrapping the above statement into __eval() function like:

```
${__eval(${__FileToString(${regusr}.txt,,)})}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables/)

---

Also be aware that it might be easier to use [Directory Listing Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/directory-listing/DirectoryListing.md) plugin instead of manually specifying file names in the CSV file, the Directory Listing Config plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried using it. But the API is not running. Is there any way that we can send the variable value in Parameter tab? This API will be running only when a value is sent through parameter. The value is a json file but it considers as a plain text /String. When I tried CSV Data config, the parameter is not passed through it. Any help would be appreciable.